# Caller Name Presentation (CNAP) enable android

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

How do I enable Caller Name Presentation (CNAP) in android?  Essentially in Canada there is an option called "Name Display" that comes with caller id.  There used to be a page here explaining it [here](http://flawless.me/wpress/) but not anymore and archive.org is of no help.

[image]

Comment: Explaining what? We don't care what other pages do or don't exist, but to help you we need to know what the problem is.

Comment: @DanHulme what more information should be added?  I added a picture.

Comment: A) What mobile network operator are you using? B) Is your network operator willing to send caller-name data to your phone (maybe in exchange for a monthly fee)? C) What make and model of phone are you using? D) Which Android version?

Comment: @unforgettableid A) verizon B) yes C) LG G4 D) Lollipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verizon Only: So it appears this used to require additional software but is now a built in according to this page http://www.cequint.com/verizon/callernameid/

ATT and Tmobile have apps but non are truly caller id.

Comment: Yes. Verizon handles their "Caller Name ID" service using an app, and they preinstall the app on Android phones which they sell.